# Is it normal for Chrome extensions to demand too many permission?

Tags: chrome, browser-extensions

I tried to install a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbdown-video-downloader/fhplmmllnpjjlncfjpbbpjadoeijkogc) for downloading Facebook video clips, but it requests too many privileges in my opinion:

> - Read and change all your data on the websites you visit
> - Manage your downloads
> - Manage your apps, extensions, and themes

Managing downloads and managing themes and extensions does not seem to be a big deal but why does it want to be able to "read and change all your data on the websites you visit"?

Comment: "Read and change all data" is required to embed download buttons and such. The manifest allows extensions to run on selected websites only, but low-effort, userscript ports usually ignore that and run on all websites.

Comment: I suspect it's requesting this permission to be able to provide download functionality for FB videos embedded at 3rd party websites, but I can't tell for sure without examining the extension in question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to quote the extension's description, it isn't just for downloading Facebook videos:

> - Download and save videos from any website (not only Facebook videos)
> - (…)
> - Downloads almost from 99% of video hosting websites

So, it makes sense for it to request permision for other websites as well.

**Edit:** After [downloading](http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) and unpacking the extension (extensions are just renamed Zip files), I can see that besides functionality for downloading Facebook videos (using code in `js/hooks/facebook.js`, it has code for downloading VKontakte videos as well as generic video embeds using the [`<video>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) and in some cases video embedded using a Flash-based player; code for these cases can be found in `js/hooks/content.js`.

Some of the code in the extension is fairly obfuscated and I haven't bothered analyzing it all, but it appears to be benign.